# How to get the file name of ms word which is currently open

Tags: php, com

I am using COM in Php and i want to get the file name of the ms word file which is currently open/Active. When i use the below code it is only giving me the output "Microsoft Word" but i need the filename too.

```
$word = new variant(com_get_active_object("word.application")); 
echo "$word";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to interact with the application object.

[Here is the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838565.aspx)

There it says, for instance, that it has a property to get the ActiveDocument.
And the active document has a property called FullName, which is a string containing the full path of the file.

I don´t know the PHP syntax, but should be something like

```
$document = word.ActiveDocument
$filename = document.FullName
```

Comment: I used as how you described but i am getting the following error                Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft Word<br/><b>Description:</b> This command is not available because no document is open.' in

Comment: This is my code now                                                                                              $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
$document = $word->ActiveDocument;
$file = $document->FullName;

Comment: Yes i will get the file name using below code as how you said  $input = "c:\\test.docx"; $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word"); $Word->Open($input); $document = $word->ActiveDocument; $file = $document->FullName;

Comment: But this not the exact solution for what i need. Here i should give the path and open ms word in the code i am using and it will return me file name as above. But i need to get the file name without passing the file name from code, if some doc file i have opened and kept then the code should return the filename of whichever doc file that is currently opened

Comment: I see. It seems that you should check application.Documents.Count > 0 because ActiveDocument raises an exception when there is none open. You should try something like  $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word"); $documents = $word->Documents->Count; and then check if it is greater than zero. Then you could ask for the active document.

Comment: Thanx for all suggestions.. I could not get what i was looking for..  So i have changed the way of doing this...

Comment: Hi Carlos, I have one more question with same topic. Have a look at the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32242912/how-to-add-text-content-to-a-word-document-using-the-current-tab-cursor-location

Comment: Yes, @Nathan. I have seen the question but I don't know the answer. It should work, because Selection is dynamically updated to the position where the cursor is when you ask. I don't understand why could it fail, except you have kept an old selection.

Comment: I am getting Ducument ->count as 0 even when some word document is already open, Am I missing anything else ? Can you please test this code and find out what is missing. $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
 $documents = $word->Documents->Count; echo $documents;

Comment: No, I can't. I don't even use PHP, nor have the wrappers built for Word, we only use Excel. But if you get that result, most likely you created a different instance of Word.application and the one you have on the screen is another, not connected to your object. Look how to get the active application instead of new COM(). There is something called GetActiveObject in COM.